# How can I retrieve RGB data for media files in javafx?

Tags: java, video, media, rgb

I am developing a video retrieval management system for my project and want to know if there is any tool to retrieve the RGB data for media files (ideally video) in java/javafx?

Comment: The answer to such a vague question is always simple: yes.

Comment: Sorry I should refer to my original question which is, HOW can I retrieve RGB data for media files in java?

Comment: I am currently looking at [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) but would appreciate an example code of how I can achieve this.